# starting subactivity for the second time causes java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, out-of-memory

I am developing a simple app which does a little bit of image-processing. It's divided in two activities; the main one with some display elements and the second one which is used to capture images off the phone's camera.
To discribe my problem: I start the app, capture an image (by starting a new Intent with the subactivity) and all data is displayed correctly. If I capture another image after this, I run in an

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError - bitmap size exceeds VM budget

I dont store the captured bitmap, in the second activity I just extract some data from it and pass it to the main-activity; finishing (finish()) the sub-activity afterwards. I really dont know what I can do about it. Thanks in advance!

greetings, Zacherl

PS: It is my first approach to android, so I apologize for any stupid beginner error I did; if someone needs any further information, I would be happy to provide it.